# CSS by data-attribute will not refresh/repaint

Tags: javascript, css, mobile-safari, repaint, custom-data-attribute

In a HTML5/JS application we have a view with some styles depending on the `data-attribute` of  elements:

like

```
<li data-level="0"></li>
```

or

```
<li data-level="1"></li>
```

CSS

```
li[data-level^="1"] {
  /* some styles */
}
```

This seems to work just fine everywhere on `page reload`.

But when the data-attribute get set programmatically via JS, the CSS properties get rendered in all relevant desktop browsers, but not in mobile safari.

JS part looks like this:

```
this.$el.attr('data-level', this.model.getLevel())
```

Any ideas on how to force to apply those properties (refresh/repaint something) ?

I would like to avoid using the class attribute and different classes as things are more complex than shown here...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ok, changing data attributes simply doesn't seem to trigger a redraw of the element in all browsers !?

Changing the `class` attribute however does.
Kind of a workaround, but does the trick.

```
this.$el
       .attr('data-level', this.model.getLevel())
       .addClass('force-repaint')
       .removeClass('force-repaint');
```

As seen here: [Changing a data attribute in Safari, but the screen does not redraw to new CSS style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934043/changing-a-data-attribute-in-safari-but-the-screen-does-not-redraw-to-new-css-s)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was working with a font icon generated with icomoon and using the data attribute `data-icon` to change the HTML entity dynamically.

On page reload, it would work in tandem with this css:

```
[data-icon]:before {
    content: attr(data-icon);
}
```

But without reload, and even by changing classes, it didn't change, just displayed the code.

```
<span class="font-icon" data-icon="&#xe901;"></span>
```

What worked for me was using [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9609450/6322400), which I edited to the following (assuming `code` in the shape of `e901`):

```
export class StringUtils {
  static emptyElement = document.createElement('div');
  static fontCodeToSymbol(code: string): string {
    let element = StringUtils.emptyElement;
    let symbol: string | nullable = `&#x${code};`;
    if (symbol && typeof symbol === 'string') {
      element.innerHTML = symbol;
      symbol = element.textContent;
      element.textContent = '';
    }
    return symbol || '';
  }
}
```

Which would directly feed the correct character in `data-icon`:

```
<span class="font-icon" data-icon=""></span>
```